# Finding Points of Intersection of the Curve $\mathbf{r}$ with the $yz$-plane

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

I want to find the point(s) where the curve defined by $\mathbf{r}(t) = \langle 2t^2-t,3t+1,1-2t \rangle$ and the $yz$-plane intersect.

The $yz$-plane is defined by the equation $x=0$, so if I set the $x$ component of $\mathbf{r}$ to $0$ and solve for $t$, I should be able to find my points of intersection.

The parametric equation for the $x$ component of $\mathbf{r}$ is

$$x = t(2t-1)$$

Letting $x=0$, we see that $t = 0$ or $t=\tfrac{1}{2}$. Therefore, the points of intersection are $(0,1,1)$ and $(0,\tfrac{5}{2},0)$.

If this is correct, then I also have seemingly extra information that I did not provide on this post, like deriving the normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ of the $yz$-plane and constructing all three parametric equations for $x,y,z$ components of $\mathbf{r}$, but it appears that what I have done above should suffice. Am I wrong? Am I not taking other factors into account?

Comment: Your solution seems correct to me.

Comment: +1: For good question formatting. It would be great if every user would take their time to ask such question. The second method gives you the same result as the normal is given by $(1,0,0)^T$. Hence it would result in $x=0$ also.

Answer (score 0):

the normal vector of the yz-plane is given by $$\vec{n}=(1;0;0)$$

Comment: In that case the normal vector of the $yz$-plane is the standard unit vector $\mathbf{I}$, which is what I was able to derive offscreen. So does that mean, intuitively, the normal vector for the $xy$-plane is $\mathbf{k}=\langle 0,0,1 \rangle$ and the normal vector for the $xz$-plane is $\mathbf{j} = \langle 0,1,0 \rangle$?

Comment: @Alana, more generally, normal vector of plane given by $ax+by+cz+d = 0$ is $(a,b,c)$.